# Out of Memory Exception - ASP.NET - IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, exception, memory, iis-7

The problem is with Memory management because I keep receiving “Out of Memory exception”. 
Here are the scenarios where we face the problem:

Please note:
1. The site/application is developed in ASP.Net and uploaded on a server with the following specs:
- Windows Server 2008 (R2) Standard
- Intel Xeon L5520@2.27GHz 2.27GHz
- RAM = 8GB
- System Type = 64bit

1. The application is event management based web application where the requirements include saving huge amount of data in Sessions etc (mentioning this in case it is relevant)
2. The applications/site works fine until we:

   - Edit a file directly on the server
   - Update a file from repository
   - Copy/Paste a file (we don’t usually edit code using this technique)
   - Please note, all of the above hold true ONLY when the traffic to the site is high that is,
   - The issue/error “Out of Memory” is not produced when the traffic/visits is low
3. Details of:

   - System Properties > Advanced > Performance Settings > Advanced tab
   - Total paging file size for all drives: 16362 MB
4. In web.config 
   Is there any way we can debug this problem to the core and find out a solution. Can you please provide links/help where we can further investigate this problem?

Best regards,
Farrukh

Answer (score 6):

Out of Memory Exceptions are common with applications that see periodic transaction surges while keeping larger volumes of data in memory.  This problem does, however, depend on your application and architecture.  Below are a few pointers:

1. Hardware - you have Xeon 5500 (Intel Nehalem chips).  These are very good at handling memory.  You should be good here.
2. OS - Windows Server 2008 R2 - As an OS this system will handle more than enough memory for you (you are good here, see link for capabilities: [Memory Limits for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx))
3. Physical Memory - Did you say you have 8 GB on the server?  Note you app is allowing 16 GB.  There is one issue.  If your app requests more memory than physically available you will see your error.  But this is not your only concern ...
4. CLR / GC limitations - Your application has a "paging file size" of 16+ GB.  This is probably your issue.

GC is the heart of your problem for you.  In terms of why, it is the same reason Java and the JVM have issues whenever an application exceeds 2-4 GB.  That requires a look at the actual process of GC.

You have "old generation" and "young generation" Garbage Collection processes.  As you app runs the CLR tries to keep your memory space organized.  These processes force all threads to pause (phase changes) when GC mark and swap processes occur.  The problem here is, depending on how your code is written and the amount of memory you keep around for long periods, you can run into memory issues.

Any time you press a runtime environment to exceed the 4 GB threshold you will see exponential increases in collection times.  When you hit the "stop the world" pause (the old gen GC where everything gets cleaned up) the CLR has to go through the entire heap and de-allocate memory.  Based on your app, 16 GB may give you issues even with more physical memory (Windows Server 2008 R2 - Enterprise or DataCenter can support 2 TB). Even if you feed it more physical memory you may see LONG collection times when your full GC hits.

Ideally I would do the following:

1. Get more physical memory (you never want to come withing 600MB of your total physical memory allocated to your application to avoid out of memory errors, but your buffer does depend on your load and the application's ability to handle it ... you may want a larger safety net to be safe).
2. Once you have the physical memory you need run GC logs while stressing the app.  This will give you an idea where you see exponential degradation in performance and what level your app can support when considering Heap size (Memory).  You may want to find a way to get your 16GB page down to a smaller size.  I do know with .Net 4.0 Microsoft has made some solid improvements to the GC process, including allowing a background thread to maintain GC.  This should give you the ability to support larger heaps (in theory) ... but nothing beats real tests on the app.  Check out this link for more info:

[Garbage Collection Performance (Asp.net 4.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx) - Also, as I am limited on links.  Navigate to the Fundamentals page for some great explanations on new GC features of ASP.Net 4.0 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#concurrent_garbage_collection)

Hope this helps!

PS - Anyone out there on lesser hardware will need to be aware of the ASP.NET use of the GC thread.  If you are running something in development like a Core Duo you have to consider that 50% of your compute power will go to GC optimization.  This means that Hardware (number of cores) is important to consider.  If you have more than you need this process should theoretically help performance.  If you are constrained on cores either get better hardware or use an older version of ASP.Net or consider turning the feature off (if possible).  Second, if latency is a concern, using "hyper-threading" does have an impact on performance as well.  You always get better performance on "physical" cores ... but that will not be a concern for 99.9% of the applications out there.

Answer (score 0):

2 GB by default. If the application is large address space aware (linked with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE), it gets 4 GB (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx)

They're still limited to 2 GB since many application depends on the top bit of pointers to be zero.

Comment: Dear, Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned already that OS is Windows 2008, 64 bit, so it can use upto 32GB memory.